# How To Call An Entire Class in Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a class navigationBtns.java that contains code for navigation buttons and their onClick() actions. That's all it does, navigation.

```
package Mobile.Smart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class navigationBtns extends Activity {

    public static ImageButton vocabButton;
    public static ImageButton shapesButton;
    public static ImageButton mathButton;
    public static ImageButton mainNextButton;

    public static Intent vocabulary;
    public static Intent shapes;
    public static Intent math;
    public static Intent mainNext;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
        /*Navigation buttons*/

        vocabButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.nextScreenWords);
        shapesButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextScreenShapes);
        mathButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextScreenMath);
        mainNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.goHome);

        vocabulary = new Intent(this,screen1.class);
        shapes = new Intent(this,screen2.class);
        math = new Intent(this,screen3.class);
        mainNext = new Intent(this,MobileSmartKidsActivity.class);

        vocabButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(vocabulary);
            }});

        shapesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(shapes);
            }});

        mathButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                startActivity(math);
            }});          

        mainNextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                startActivity(mainNext);
            }});

      }
}
```

In the same package I have MobileSmartKidsActivity which plays a video and then has the same navigation buttons specified in navigationBtns.java. (There's 3 other files that use the same buttons). I have rewritten the code for all buttons in all the separate java files which is overly redundant and memory consuming. How can I just call the navigationBtns class within the MobileSmartKidsActivity class? I've done it before in Java3D but I don't know how to do it in Android.

package Mobile.Smart;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import Mobile.Smart.navigationBtns;

public class MobileSmartKidsActivity extends Activity {

    private VideoView vd;
    private ImageButton vocabularyButton;
    private ImageButton shapesButton;
    private ImageButton mathButton;
    private ImageButton mainNextButton;

    private Intent vocabulary;
    private Intent shapes;
    private Intent math;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        /*load and play video on home page*/        
        vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.nursery);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        vd.setMediaController(mc);
        vd.setVideoURI(uri);
        vd.start();

        vocabularyButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.nextScreenWords);
        shapesButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextScreenShapes);
        mathButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextScreenMath);
        mainNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.goHome);

        vocabulary = new Intent(this,screen1.class);
        shapes = new Intent(this,screen2.class);
        math = new Intent(this,screen3.class);

        vocabularyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                startActivity(vocabulary);
            }});

        shapesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                startActivity(shapes);
            }});

        mathButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                startActivity(math);
            }});          

        mainNextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                       @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {}});                
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ButtonUtil class that has a static method that takes the navigation buttons as parameters and initialize them. Now you just need to call the method in both onCreate methods.

Comment: I've tried this. The app runs but the buttons don't respond. This is what the navigationBtn class looks like now:

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the buttons part as a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and then just add this to all the needed activities. That way the code for the buttons will only be in one place.

**Note:** Fragments require API Level 11 or greater.

Comment: I'll give this a try but I'm still a newbie at this so I gotta read up a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just put the nav button code into an activity class like you have and then extend from that class instead of Activity when you create all of your other activities.